# 100% ширина блока до следующего блока

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток.

Есть несколько страниц, на одной странице две колоны (контент + меню), на других одна (контент).
Есть "настройки" которые должны располагаться по центру блока "контента".
На странице с "меню" ширина вычисляется с помощью calc из 100% и "пустого блока" с шириной меню, но на других страницах этого блока нет. Собственно интересует как можно расположить 2 блока, левый из которых будет всегда 100%. Чтобы без проблем убирать из кода правый блок. Возможно есть иное решение?

Спасибо.

[Ссылка на Codepen](https://codepen.io/lapqa/pen/gOpgRYp)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block element-1">100% - 50px</div>
<div class="block element-2">50px</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="block element-3">100%</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="block element-3">100%</div>
<div class="block element-4">50px</div>
</div>
```

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  background-color: #373150;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-decoration-skip: ink;
  font-family: -apple-system-headline, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, sans-serif;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.block {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#EF6174;
  color:white;
  font-size:0.8em;
  text-align:center; 
  line-height:4em;
}

.container {
  display:block;
  max-width:900px;
  margin:0 auto 20px auto;
}

.element-1 {
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width: calc( 100% - 50px );
}

.element-2 {
  float:left;
  width: 40px;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.element-3 {
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.element-4 {
  float:left;
  width: 40px;
  height:50px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. В `.container` ставите `display: flex;`

```
.container {
  display: flex;

...

}
```

https://codepen.io/roman-seredenko/pen/yLNgoyZ

Comment: Вас не смущают ошибки в примере?

Comment: В целом, то что нужно. НО почему ширина не такая как установлена? У себя ставлю 280px, по факту 225,44px. Ставлю 300px, по факту 238,23px?

В любом случае огромное спасибо. Открыл для себя что то новое.

Comment: @NNMASSN Вероятно из-за margin или же комбинация размеров выставлена не коректно. Для управления размерами блоков внутри display: flex; служат три свойства flex-grow, flex-shrink и flex-basis. Свойство width не стоит использовать.

Comment: @Roman, огромное спасибо! Не сталкивался с таким еще, будем изучать.